# How to collect certain cells based on header column and row values

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a program which searches through a column for a specified string value then it copies the 6 cells adjacent to that cell.
However, I would now like to

1. search for the row string value
2. copy cells in that row whos columns contain a header string as well.
   Below is a sub in my current macro.

```vb
Sub PasteCI()
     Dim c As Range, cDest As Range
        
      
        Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
        Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next paste destination. C2?
        
        If c Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
            cDest.Resize(6, 1).Value = "-"       'fill placeholders
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy    'got match - copy range
            cDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                  Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
End Sub
```

Variable Definitions

```vb
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo f
         Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
           On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    f:
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Uncompatable Workbook Open. Please Open approriate Workbook "
End Property

Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
    Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property

Property Get col() As Long
        col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="DSCR", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get col2() As Long
        On Error GoTo e
        col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
         On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    e:
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "No Name of Project Found. Please Manually Enter Into Sheet"
End Property
    
Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
        On Error GoTo desterr
        Set wsDest = Workbooks("LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    desterr:
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Destination Spreadsheet not Open. Please Open"
End Property
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Please share some data and your expected output. Reading [repro] and using  [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) will help you to improve your question. Then it is much easier to help you.

Comment: I think you're talking about `Intersect`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Intersect

Comment: Not clear what you need. Please add examples (show inputs and expected outputs + logic used to get there)